# laravel 5.2 - passing route parameter to controller

Tags: laravel, controller, routes

I have the following route in a Laravel application:

`Route::get('/post/view/{id}', 'PostController@getView');`

However I am unsure how to use the id passed as a parameter in the Controller method PostController@getView.

Is there a simple way to pass the route parameter into the desired controller method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this code? This method should be in your controller.

```
   public function getView($id)
   {
      dd($id);
   }
```

Let me know if that helped.

Thanks

Comment: If you think this has helped you , can you please mark this as the correct answer - this might help someone in the future - thanks

Comment: You should take a look at Route-Model binding, if you set this up and replace {id} with {post}, $post automatically becomes an instance of the Post model without you having to find it in your controller.

Comment: Here is example with demo code: 
http://www.devtrainings.com/2016/04/laravel-how-to-get-route-parameters-in-controller.html